# Locating files by name for copying elsewhere

Tags: python, search, filenames, shutil

New to Python...
I'm trying to have python take a text file of file names (new name on each row), and store them as strings ...

i.e

```
import os, shutil       
files_to_find = []
with open('C:\\pathtofile\\lostfiles.txt') as fh:
    for row in fh:
        files_to_find.append(row.strip)
```

...in order to search for these files in directories and then copy any found files somewhere else...

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('D:\\'):
for _file in files:
    if _file in files_to_find:
       print ("Found file in: " + str(root))
        shutil.copy(os.path.abspath(root + '/' + _file), 'C:\\destination')
```

print ("process completed")

Despite knowing these files exist, the script runs without any errors but without finding any files.

I added...

```
print (files_to_find)
```

...after the first block of code to see if it was finding anything and saw screeds of "built-in method strip of str object at 0x00000000037FC730>,

Does this tell me it's not successfully creating strings to compare file names against? I wonder where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Did you mean `row.strip()`?

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use array to create a list of files.

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import shutil


def file_names(self,filepattern,dir):
    os.chdir(dir)
    count = len(glob.glob(filepattern))
    file_list = []
    for line in sorted(glob.glob(filepattern)):
        line = line.split("/")
        line = line[-1]
        file_list.append(line)
    return file_list
```

The loop over the array list to compare.